# convert from SQL to HQL gives error Grails

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, hql

I am trying to convert this sql to hql to fetch the data from artifact table. I have this sql query which works fine on the database

```
select a.*
from classification c 
     join (select id from taxonomy_node start with id = 5067 connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id) h
     on (c.node_id = h.id)
     join artifact a on (a.id = c.artifact_id)
     Where a.DOCUMENT_ID = 10462 AND c.active=1
```

I am trying to convert it to HQL

```
artifacts = Artifact.executeQuery("FROM classification c "+
                                        "JOIN (SELECT id FROM taxonomy_node START WITH id = :nodeId "+
                                        "CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR id = parent_id) h "+
                                        "ON (c.node_id = h.id) "+
                                        "JOIN artifact a ON (a.id = c.artifactId) "+
                                        "WHERE a.DOCUMENT_ID = :docid AND c.active=1",
                                        [nodeId: NodeId ,docid: document.id],
                                        [max:limit, offset:startIndex])
```

The domain classes look like 
**Classification**

```
class Classification {

    public static final String USER_DEFAULT = "USER"
    public static final String USER_SYSTEM = "SYSTEM"

    TaxonomyNode node
    String artifactId //TODO can we drive this with an annotated object or something?
    Boolean active
    String createdBy
    String updatedBy
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    // or should we create an Artifact Toolkit plugin?

    static constraints = {
        node nullable:false, blank:false
        artifactId nullable:false, blank:false, unique: ['node']
        active nullable: false, blank: false
        createdBy nullable:false, blank:false
        updatedBy nullable:false, blank:false
    }

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'classification_seq']
        artifactId index: 'classify_by_artifact_node'
        node index: 'classify_by_artifact_node'
        active defaultValue: "1"
    }
}
```

**Artifact** looks like

```
class Artifact {

    public enum ArtifactType {
        CLAUSE("Clause"),
        TITLE("Title"),
        DEFINED_TERMS("Defined Terms")

        private final String value

        ArtifactType(String value) { this.value = value }
        String toString() { value }
        String getKey() { name() }
    }

    public enum ArtifactStatus {
        ALL("All"),
        REVIEWED("Reviewed"),
        FOR_REVIEW("For Review"),
        UNCLASSIFIED("Unclassified")

        private final String value

        ArtifactStatus(String value) { this.value = value }
        String toString() { value }
        String getKey() { name() }
    }

    Document document
    String artifactType
    String text
    String status
    String createdBy
    String updatedBy
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static belongsTo = Document
    static hasMany = [classification: Classification]

    static constraints = {
        artifactType maxSize: 50, nullable: false, blank: false
        text nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 4000
        status nullable:true, blank:true
        createdBy nullable:false, blank:false
        updatedBy nullable:false, blank:false
    }

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'artifact_seq']
        document index: 'artifact_by_doc'
        artifactType index: 'artifact_by_doc,artifact_by_type'
        text index: 'artifact_by_doc,artifact_by_text'
    }
}
```

the **taxonomy Node** looks like

```
class TaxonomyNode {

    public static final String USER_DEFAULT = "USER"
    public static final String USER_SYSTEM = "SYSTEM"

    String hierarchyId
    String nodeId
    String label
    String inputFormat
    Boolean active
    String createdBy
    String updatedBy
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [metadata: TaxonomyNodeMetadata]

    TaxonomyNode parent

    static constraints = {
        inputFormat nullable:true, blank:true //TODO for now we want to allow null/blank for user-entered nodes
        parent nullable:true //TODO we should enforce that only one node per hierarchyId can have a null parent
        hierarchyId nullable:false, blank:false //TODO we should enforce the parent's hierarchyId is the same
        active nullable: false, blank: false
        nodeId nullable:false, blank:false, unique: ['hierarchyId']
        label nullable:true, blank:true
        createdBy nullable:false, blank:false
        updatedBy nullable:false, blank:false
    }

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'taxonomy_node_seq']
        hierarchyId index: 'taxonomy_by_hier'
        label index: 'taxonomy_by_hier,taxonomy_by_label'
        parent index: 'taxonomy_by_hier,taxonomy_by_parent'
        active defaultValue: "1"
    }
}
```

I am getting this **error**

```
Error |
2014-10-22 09:22:38,633 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR ast.ErrorCounter  - line 1:28: unexpected token: (
Error |
2014-10-22 09:22:38,634 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR ast.ErrorCounter  - line 1:28: unexpected token: (
Message: unexpected token: (
    Line | Method
->>  281 | $tt__index in com.ald.aeandsdx.ArtifactController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter   in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run        in java.lang.Thread
Error |
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 28 [FROM classification c JOIN (SELECT id FROM taxonomy_node START WITH id = :nodeId CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR id = parent_id) hON (c.node_id = h.id) JOIN artifact a ON (a.id = c.artifactId) WHERE a.DOCUMENT_ID = :docid AND c.active=1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 28 [FROM classification c JOIN (SELECT id FROM taxonomy_node START WITH id = :nodeId CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR id = parent_id) hON (c.node_id = h.id) JOIN artifact a ON (a.id = c.artifactId) WHERE a.DOCUMENT_ID = :docid AND c.active=1]
```

Comment: Usually you don't do explicit joins in HQL - Hibernate already knows the relationships. It can be done, but it's rare. Also - do a full conversion from SQL to HQL. `parent_id`, `c.node_id`, `a.DOCUMENT_ID`, and `c.active=1` appear to be invalid - you have column names, but must use property names, and `active` is Boolean, so it will never be equal to `1`. Hibernate will pass HQL that it knows is probably valid but doesn't know how to handle (e.g. CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR) to the generated SQL, but this is not reliable because of the other conversions. You might be better off leaving it as SQL.

Answer (score 1):

HQL supports subqueries only in SELECT and WHERE clauses, see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Comment: you mean conenct by is not allowed ?

Comment: yes, the one with connect. here you will find how to write joins in hql: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins