# Raw SQL in Grails using hibernate session :Error

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, grails, hql

I am trying to execute this SQL in grails using hibernate session. This SQL will should return contents from the artifact table.  What is wrong with this code ?

```
final session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
final  String query  = "select a.* from classification c join (select id from taxonomy_node "+ 
                                                        "start with id = :nodeId connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id) h " +
                                                        "on (c.node.id = h.id) join artifact a on (a.id = c.artifact_id) " +
                                                        "Where a.DOCUMENT.ID = :docid AND c.active=1 ";
final sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);
artifact = sqlQuery.with {
        addEntity(Artifact, Classificatio, TaxonomyNode);
        setLong('nodeId',filterByAssociatedNodeId);
        setLong('docid',document.id);       
        list();
}
```

Error that I am getting

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sessionFactory for class: com.th.ald.aeandsdx.ArtifactController
```

I also tried a few oher thisn like converting this sql to HQL as in [convert sql to hql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508270/convert-from-sql-to-hql-gives-error-grails)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the weirdest question I've seen in a while. Look at your first line of code. Read the error message you showed us. Why are you looking at anything other than that one line of code?

You are using a variable that has no value. It's not a database problem, not a SQL vs HQL issue, not a Grails problem, just a plain old boring programming problem. Assign a valid value and move on :)

But how do we get access to this mysterious `sessionFactory`'s missing value? The `SessionFactory` is a singleton Spring bean, so dependency injection is your best bet. If you're running this in a service, controller, domain class, or other artifact type that supports dependency injection, add a field-scope variable to the class, e.g.

```
class MyService {...

   def sessionFactory

   def someMethod(int foo, boolean bar) {
      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

This works because Grails uses auto-injection by name, and properties like this have a setter method generated by the Groovy compiler that Spring will see and call to inject the bean instance, and you can get past line #1.

It doesn't work inside methods though. If you add `def someBeanName` inside a method, it's a local variable, not a class property, so it's not visible to Spring and will be null.

Comment: thanks. defining session Factory in the class instead of method worked. There is something wrong with the setLong method I am getting an  error saying groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.thomsonreuters.ald.aeandsdx.ArtifactController.setLong() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [nodeId, 5067]

Comment: Once again, the error is clear and right there in front of you :)  The method is `setLong`, so you'd expect the 2nd arg to be a number. The value looks like a number, but it's telling you that you passed a String. So convert it. There are several ways, I'd use the `as` operator `setLong('docid',document.id as Long)`

Comment: well new error pops up. I was wondering wouldnt it be easiar to convert this to HQL ? and use a findall /executeQuery becasue I am trying to do pagiantion

Comment: I have no idea what this means 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: artifact for class: com..ald.aeandsdx.ArtifactController

Comment: Time for a new question I think, this one's getting full

Comment: ok Ill post a new question. Do you think you can help with me this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508270/convert-from-sql-to-hql-gives-error-grails

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you're using "final"?

Anyhow, not sure if that is an issue or not, here is what I can recommend from a similar situation where I needed raw SQL. I returned a Map instead of a set of objects, I had issues since I wasn't defining the relationships in my domain classes and leveraging GORM the traditional way.

The code I would change would be:

```
final sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query).setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
.addScalar("ALIAS_VALUE_FROM_SELECT", new StringType())
.addScalar("ALIAS_VALUE_FROM_SELECT", new TimestampType())
.addScalar("ALIAS_VALUE_FROM_SELECT", new BooleanType())
.addScalar("ALIAS_VALUE_FROM_SELECT", new ShortType())
.addScalar("ALIAS_VALUE_FROM_SELECT", new LongType())
```

Make sure to alias your columns and list them out instead of a.*, there are all the types that you need for addScalar, this way you can ensure that you have the right type. It's a bit verbose, but this way you at least get the results that you're expecting.

```
List<Map<String,Object>> artifact = sqlQuery.list()
```

I don't think it would really matter whether it's a list of objects or list of maps, at the end you get the results that will work for you.